# Error When Using Protocol as a Type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, dictionary, protocols

I'm using Swift and trying to make some collection objects.  These collection objects have a backing `Dictionary` to hold custom objects.  For example, an object might be of type `Cat` and the collection object would be of type `Cats`.  `Cats` would have a private dictionary containing values of type `Cat`.  I have other types that also need respective collections (each collection type has specific logic for the type it holds).

I created a protocol to ensure each collection has a few common characteristics.  These common functions and subscripts are generally passthroughs to the backing dictionary.  Here is the protocol:

```
protocol ObjectDictionaryProtocol {

    // These are necessary for generics to work in protocols
    typealias Key: Hashable
    typealias Value


    // MARK: - Properties

    var count: Int { get }
    var isEmpty: Bool { get }
    var keys: LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<Key, Value>, Key> { get }
    var values: LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<Key, Value>, Value> { get }


    // MARK: - Subscripts

    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? { get set }

}
```

When I go to actually use the protocol as a type, for instance:

```
var objects: ObjectDictionaryProtocol
```

or

```
init(objs: ObjectDictionaryProtocol) {
    ...
}
```

I get the error:

```
Protocol 'ObjectDictionaryProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

I've searched around and it looks like the `Hashable` protocol I'm conforming to for my `Key` `typealias` is causing this.  What is the best way to get around this?  Is there a way to change the protocol such that I don't need the `Hashable`, or do I need to do something in the class that is using `ObjectDictionaryProtocol`?  Or maybe there's a better way to effectively 'subclass' a Swift `Dictionary` (quotes because I realize the `Dictionary` `struct` cannot be subclassed)?

Comment: Actually if you strip everything down, you'll see that just using a typealias in your protocol prohibits you from using the protocol as a type, as is explained in the error message: _"... or associated type requirements"_. If you include a typealias, you include an associated type. I suggest you make use of custom structure instead which conforms to your protocol.

Answer (score 0):

A protocol with associated types is less a type and more a template for a type.  The actual type exists when the protocol's associated types are specified.  Thus `ObjectDictionaryProtocol` 'becomes' a type when you specify:

```
ObjectDictionaryProtocol<String,Cat>
```

but the above is not valid Swift...

So you asked... '*[is there] a better way to effectively 'subclass' a Swift Dictionary*'.  You might get by with an `extension` with something like:

```
class Cat {}

extension Dictionary where Value : Cat {
  func voice (name: Key) {
    if let _ = self[name] {
      print ("\(name): Meow")
    }
  }
}

var someCats = Dictionary<String,Cat>()
someCats["Spot"] = Cat()
someCats.voice("Spot")
// Spot: Meow
```

Or you may need to actually implement the protocol.

```
class ObjectDiciontary<Key:Hashable, Value> : ObjectDictionaryProtocol {
  var backingDictionary = Dictionary<Key,Value>()
  // implement protocol
}

var object : ObjectDictionary<String,Cat> = ...
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because when you're using `typealias` you're effectivly making your `Protocol` into a generic protocol as `Protocol<T>`. Bear with me here, I'll explain why and how to fix it.

The issue here is that Apple has decided to make `typealias` the keyword for defining associated types. This is fixed in Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7.3)
You can read more about it on https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0011-replace-typealias-associated.md

It's being renamed to `associatedtype` which makes more sense.

This means your protocol has to be adopted, and there define its associated types.

In your case it would look something like

```
protocol ObjectDictionaryProtocol {
  associatedtype Value
}

extension String : ObjectDictionaryProtocol {
  associatedtype = Double
}
```

The init could look like

```
 init<T : ObjectDictionaryProtocol>(objs: ObjectDictionaryProtocol)
```

or

```
init<T : ObjectDictionaryProtocol 
     where T.Value == Double>(objs: ObjectDictionaryProtocol)
```

Now for `typealias Key: Hashable` it means that whatever type that is assigned to `Key` has to conform or be `Hashable`

This will give you an error that `String` isn't conforming to `ObjectDictionaryProtocol` as it can't fulfil the requirements.

```
protocol ObjectDictionaryProtocol {
  associatedtype Value : FloatingPointType
}

extension String : ObjectDictionaryProtocol {
  associatedtype = Int
}
```

`Int` isn't a `FloatingPointType` (but `Double` is)